# Calendar view in android should display 1 week from current date

Tags: java, android, eclipse, calendarview

I am trying to get the CalendarView widget to display only 1 week from current date. I tried using ,

```
Date date = new Date();
cal = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);
cal.setMaxDate(date.getTime()+604800000);
cal.setMinDate(date.getTime());
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Really appreciate if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

u can set like this here eg. i set the date to 25 -12(december)- current year. You want something like: just get  1 week from current date and u can set like this also

```
public static Calendar defaultCalendar() {
    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11); // Months are 0-based!
    currentDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 25); // Clearer than DATE
    return currentDate;
}
```